# Project architecture: service for working only with database

Tags: database, rest, architecture

i am just wondering how good is this approach to project architecture:

1) You have N services that do X stuff. But there is one constraint - they dont have their own database and they can not access any database directly.

2) For that i have a DB service which can access DB and do any action against that.

So the worklow is like this: If any service needs something from a database it asks database service for the records.

How well is this kind of architecture? Am i running into serious bottlenecks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than put your entire database behind a single service and single interface, think about providing separate services for different parts of your dataset according to interfaces driven by your high-level business rules and data model (e.g. user account data service, orders data service, audit log data service). That way you can mock/scale/deploy these independent parts differently according to need and more easily change the backend storage if required later (e.g. archived order retrieval from different db). Also because the data managed by a service is of a particular type, certain decisions can be made independently for each service (e.g. caching policy - config-type data could be cached, active orders data probably not).

Initially you can implement all of these interfaces in a single service and then separate later, but the key to this approach is getting the interfaces abstracted and segregated cleanly.

Comment: Wow. This is a very clever suggestion separating even more logic.

Comment: I recommend that you read up on microservice/SOA architecture and 'clean' architecture.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty typical architecture - It's a good idea to write your service's data access code against an abstraction so that you can unit test with a mocked version of your data.

At the least, it's a good idea to consolidate your data access code in one place so that you can make changes to it easily.